# CORS Response Header (Intermittently) not being returned in IIS - Web API

Tags: .net, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have an issue where I have enabled CORS in my Web API. The OPTIONS request to the server is returning the correct CORS Headers. But if I change any thing in the web.config of the API then no CORS headers are returned
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:"*".

To get the Web.API to work again I have to make the change to web.config. Recompile my web api and deploy with a different version number and the api will then function and return my CORS headers during the OPTIONS pre-flight checks

Edit: adding registration and cors enabled code Global.asax.cs:

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
           GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);           
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
        }
```

in the WebApiConfig.cs:

```
 public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {

        config.EnableCors();         

        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.
                    SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Services.Add(typeof(IExceptionLogger), new GlobalExceptionLogger());
        config.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler), new GlobalExceptionHandler());......
```

Further to this...I left the API operational when I left the office...then a couple of hours later the API stopped working again without having to change anything. I'm guessing here but it looks like the application_Start routine is not called when the application pool recycles or the configuration of CORS and Routes are forgotten after a recycle etc...

Comment: Can you show the code that is enabling CORS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking about what I posted in the edit...and making the assumption that the CORS was being disabled after a app pool recycle. I decided to move the  piece of code the enables the CORS `config.EnableCors();` in the `class WebApiConfig` to `protected void Application_Start()` in the global.asax file. So my `Application_Start()` routine looks something like this now:

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnableCors();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);`
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you enable CORS you do this NOT with help of Web.config but using a package:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
```

and adding appropriate attributes whenever you need, or develop your own HTTP filter.

Comment: Thats all good - I have enabled cors using the NUget package you describe above..., and I get the API operational with all the headers etc working. My problem is that when I change anything in the web.config (e.g. Appsetting - key) My client application will get the following error:(CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing) when I make a call to an API method : - I then have to recompile the applcaition and deploy again to get the cors working again

Comment: @Paul I don't think it's a CORS issue. Most likely your application stops working because of some other reason. Obviously it doesn't send CORS headers in this case and client app throws CORS related error. Please make sure your app is functioning after web.config changing.

Comment: It is functioning fine after the config change - I can add whitespace to the web.conig and the CORS response headers are then not sent to the calling browser.- I have to basically reset the application to get the application to send CORS response headers